# Preferable way to get rid of 'redefined-outer-name' from pylint

Tags: python, python-3.x, pylint

For the following `Python` code

```
def add_func(a,b):
    print(a+b)

a = 2
b = 3
add_func(a,b)
```

`pylint` will state

```
 W0621: Redefining name 'a' from outer scope (line 4) (redefined-outer-name)
...
```

I can rename it as (perhaps due to `a` and `b` outside function will interfere `add_func`)

```
a_input = 2
b_input = 3
add_func(a_input,b_input)
```

to get rid of the message from `pylint`. But, `_input` looks somehow lengthy. Is there any recommended coding practice to get rid of the `outer scope` message from `pylint`?

Comment: It's simple: don't have any global variables. Put everything in functions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the main usecase of a function is to pass arguments directly into it, so in this case the simplest way to input those would be:

```
add_func(2,3)
```

If you want to pass in varibales, name them after their usecase for readability purposes (It is generally not recommended to have a single char as variable name, with a few exceptions like i for loops)